# Strange playlist item list responded from YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

youtube api responses wrong video items of this kind of playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_lSUrVP8K-w63I5BQyJKXdoxZNkMvU1T6w
You guys can see the actual api response [**by this link**](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?playlistId=OLAK5uy_lSUrVP8K-w63I5BQyJKXdoxZNkMvU1T6w&maxResults=25&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails)

This is a video returned from the api:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdq1DWaxrJ0
But it doesn't exists in the playlist above, moreover I can't play this video because `The uploader has not made this video available in your country.` It looks like a "special video" of YouTube Music, lets see it thumbnail: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Fc3Mj63xmPo/maxresdefault.jpg

Anyone know what happened?

Comment: Hello. Did you find a workaround to get correct playlist items? I'm experiencing this issue too.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem: "Vdq1DWaxrJ0" isn't returned when accessing https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&playlistId=OLAK5uy_lSUrVP8K-w63I5BQyJKXdoxZNkMvU1T6w&key=YOUR_API_KEY&maxResults=50